# how to skip x number of tests in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

lets say we have a test suite that takes 5 minutes

lets say it fails at 90%

lets say it fails at 95%

rather than running it 3 times ( once to 90, once to 95, and once 100% )
~14 minutes

i would like to run it twice-ish ( once from 0 to 90, once from 90 to 95, 95 to 100, and once all the way through to make sure it all works )
if i'm fast about restarting it ~10-11 minutes

so when it fails, i'd like to to output the spec number ( based on current tests )
and then i need to have it start at that number when i run again from command line
so, how do i get rspec to run using something like `rspec spec/ --startat 321`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think something like this would work, since RSpec runs test in random order by default to ensure they are not dependent on their order. Maybe a fitting solution would be to note down the failing tests and running just those. You can run specific tests like this:

```
rspec /spec/controllers/example_controller_spec.rb:19
```

Where `19` is the line that your test is located at. After you fixed all failing tests, you could then rerun the whole test suite to make sure everything is fine.

Comment: I think it would work.  It should scrape the directory in the same fashion each time.  It loads all the descriptions.  Randomness is not turned on in our case.  This should be a couple of lines of code in the right places for someone who knows the rspec gem.  One to increment as it looks at each test, and one to skip tests as they're queued up until it hits the argument from command line.  I'll give you credit though since this is more of a feature request and could soon turn into a hack.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have can be addressed through the use of the `--tag` option in rspec. You could apply tags to the groups that are failing and then write a small script to execute them in the order you want. Here is the [rspec docs page on tags](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-12/docs/command-line/tag-option).

> Use the --tag (or -t) option to filter the examples by tags.
>
> The tag can be a simple name or a name:value pair. In the first case,
>   examples with :name => true will be filtered. In the second case,
>   examples with :name => value will be filtered, where value is always a
>   string. In both cases, name is converted to a symbol.
>
> Tags can also be used to exclude examples by adding a ~ before the
>   tag. For example ~tag will exclude all examples marked with :tag =>
>   true and ~tag:value will exclude all examples marked with :tag =>
>   value.
>
> To be compatible with the Cucumber syntax, tags can optionally start
>   with an @ symbol, which will be ignored.

Some examples from the doc page:

```
describe "group with tagged specs" do
  it "example I'm working now", :focus => true do; end
  it "special example with string", :type => 'special' do; end
  it "slow example", :skip => true do; end
  it "ordinary example", :speed => 'slow' do; end
end
```

This would be easier than using line numbers or excluding individual examples manually. Hope this helps.

Comment: We have a giant test directory, so editting individual tests isn't really an option.  While I'm fixing a test, I'll `:focus` it, isolating it and making it work.  The question is regarding how to continue from that point, so I don't have to retest all the beginning tests.  I heard rspec is potentially adding a feature such as this in future releases, so each test would be numbered and one could resume from any point in time.